# Vue.js component for adding/removing items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Simple Vue.js component, where you can add a wrestler via an AJAX endpoint, and remove a wrestler from an AJAX endpoint.

Any notes on whether I’m doing this the “Vue.js way” or tips for improvement are greatly welcomed.

The HTML template portion of the component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-if="loading">Loading&hellip;</p>
        <div v-else>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item" v-for="(wrestler, index) in wrestlersSortedByName" v-bind:key="wrestler.id">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" v-on:click.prevent="removeWrestler(wrestler, index)">
                        <span class="btn-text">{{ wrestler.name }}</span>
                        <span class="btn-icon" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="name" required ref="name" v-bind:disabled="busy" v-model="name" v-on:keydown.enter.prevent="addWrestler" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click.prevent="addWrestler" v-bind:disabled="busy">
                            <span class="btn-text" v-html="submitText" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The JavaScript portion of the component:

```js
const confirm = require('./../mixins/confirm.js');

export default {
    computed: {
        submitText() {
            return this.busy ? 'Submitting&hellip;' : 'Add wrestler';
        },
        wrestlersSortedByName() {
            return this.wrestlers.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
            });
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            busy: false,
            loading: true,
            name: '',
            wrestlers: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addWrestler() {
            this.busy = true;

            axios.post(this.action, { name: this.name })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.wrestlers.push(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch((response) => {
                    alert('Error adding wrestler to video.');
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.busy = false;
                    this.name = '';
                    this.$refs.name.focus();
                });
        },
        loadWrestlers() {
            axios.get(this.action).then((response) => {
                this.wrestlers = response.data.data;
                this.loading = false;
            });
        },
        removeWrestler(wrestler, index) {
            const message = `Are you sure you wish to remove ${wrestler.name} from this video?`;

            this.confirm(message, () => {
                axios.delete(`${this.action}/${wrestler.id}`)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.wrestlers.splice(index, 1);
                    })
                    .catch((response) => {
                        alert('Error removing wrestler.');
                    });
            });
        }
    },
    mixins: [
        confirm
    ],
    mounted() {
        this.loadWrestlers();
    },
    props: {
        action: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the contents of **./mixins/confirm.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        confirm(message, callback) {
            if (window.confirm(message)) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Style notes: I’m aware of the `@` shorthand for `v-on:`, but prefer the longer form as it looks more HTML-y to me.

Comment: @SamOnela Not sure I follow? `this.action` is a URL, i.e. `http://example.com/videos/1/wrestlers`, so is just a string.

Comment: Oh sorry - I was confusing the `data` and `props` properties

Comment: @SamOnela Ah, yeah. It’s a bit awkward as the API returns a JSON response nested in a `data` key!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code makes good use of basic VueJS concepts and practices- using computed properties, binding values, conditional display with `v-if`, etc.

I also like the application of arrow functions, promise handling, etc.

<strike>I see there is a *key* attribute bound to the list items (i.e. `v-bind:key="wrestler.id"`). Correct me if I am wrong but that doesn't appear to be an attribute of [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li). What is that used for?</strike> **Edit:** Oh yes, thanks for reminding me about the [key attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for list editing

Then in the `addWrestler()` method, there are two `.then()` callbacks. Is there a reason not to move the three lines in the second callback into the first?

```
axios.get(this.action, { name: this.name })
    .then((response) => {
        this.wrestlers.push(response.data.data);
        this.busy = false;
        this.name = '';
        this.$refs.name.focus();
    })
    .catch(...)
```

If you really wanted to shorten the code for the promise callbacks, you could abstract those into methods.

Comment: Thanks. The `v-bind:key` is something that seems to be recommended by Vue to “identify” nodes in a list: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key. The second `then()` callback in the example pointed out was to DRY the code out a bit: I wanted to do those things whether the request succeeded or failed, so chained another `then()` callback to avoid copying it into both the first `then()` and `catch()` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about [the key attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for list rendering. And good call with the DRYness!